# How to define one to many relationship in factory?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

- Board has many posts.
- User has many posts.

I want to make dummy posts. I created dummy users and boards. What should I fill in `board_id` and `user_id`?

```
class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'board_id' => ,
            'user_id' =>, 
            'title' => $this->faker->, 
            'content' => $this->faker->,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a one-to-many relationship? It looks like you're heading for a many-to-many relationship based on your request.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Sorry, the question is a liitle bit confused. But I found solution [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/factory-with-a-foreign-key)